# Convert string to Float with dot and also comma

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, string, dataframe

This is the column of a dataframe that I have (values are str):

| Values |
| --- |
| 7257.5679 |
| 6942.0949714286 |
| 5780.0125476250005 |

This is how I want the record to go to the database:

| Values |
| --- |
| 7.257,56 |
| 6.942,09 |
| 5.780,01 |

How can I do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to store them with a dot and a comma? Will you store them as string?

Comment: It would be better to store the numbers as proper numbers i.e. `7257.56` then you can do basic and simple maths on them without having to convert those strings to numbers first

Comment: If they are numbers, you should store them as numbers (float, decimal, integer, etc). Storing them as strings is a mistake. Then you can format those numbers as you want in your presentation layer

Comment: @JoanLaraGanau In the bank the column is decimal, I think in the USA it is different, but in my country numbers are separated like this: 7.257,56

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
df["Values"] = df["Values"].apply(lambda x: "{:,.2f}".format(float(x)))
```

Output:

```
     Values
0  7,257.57
1  6,942.09
2  5,780.01
```

To get `values` in the format `7.257,56`. You can make good use of the `replace` function:

```py
df["Values"] = df["Values"].apply(lambda x: "{:,.2f}".format(float(x)).replace(".", ",").replace(",", ".", 1))
```

But `replace` might not be more efficient and concise when dealing with larger dataset, in that case you might want to look into `translate`, that will be the **best** approach to go with.

```py
trans_column = str.maketrans(",.", ".,")
df["Values"] = df["Values"].apply(lambda x: "{:,.2f}".format(float(x)).translate(trans_column))
```

Output:

```
     Values
0  7.257,57
1  6.942,09
2  5.780,01
```

Comment: Almost, the comma and point are swapped, it should be 7,257.57!

Comment: @PythOn I edited the answer. You can take a look at it.